# Keyboard white flickering with React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, animation, react-native, flicker

When showing and hiding the keyboard in my React Native app there is a white flickering where the keyboard goes, see this:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/Bwmin9T1R4OAO9tB3

I'm making my first app using React Native, so I'm not sure if this is "expected" behaviour (if this is just the way things look with React Native) or if there is anything I can do to fix it.

- Everything starting from the animated icon down to the USD field is
  wrapped in a `<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">` (I tried
  removing it and still see the flickering).
- I use `Keyboard` from "react-native" to listen to "keyboardDidShow" and "keyboardDidHide", and use `Animated` from "react-native" to perform the animation on the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to a newer version of `create-react-native-app` which utilizes Expo seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Expo and you're still having this issue, changing the `softwareKeyboardLayoutMode` in the `app.json` worked for me.

```
"android": {
    "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
    ...(other properties)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` fixed it for me.

Solution found in this comment.