# White flickering when keyboard pops up in my react native app

Tags: react-native

I'm using expo sdk 40. Tried changing backgroundColor prop in app.json and still no change . Is it a known issue in react native?

Comment: You will need to provide some code for anyone to offer advice. The screen shouldn't flicker unless your app tells it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Expo, changing the `softwareKeyboardLayoutMode` in the `app.json` worked for me.

```
"android": {
    "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
    ...(other properties)
}
```

[Keyboard white flickering with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975401/keyboard-white-flickering-with-react-native/68358813#68358813)